# Compare values in Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I'm using .conf which contain keys and values.

Some keys contains numbers like

**deployment.conf**

```
EAR_COUNT=2
EAR_1=xxx.ear
EAR_2=yyy.ear
```

When I try to retrieve that value using particular key and compare with integer value i.e. natural number.

But Whatever I retrieved values from .conf ,it is should be String datatype.

How should I compare both value in Linux Bash script.

Simply : How should I compare two values in Linux.?

Ex :

```
. ./deployment.conf

count=$EAR_COUNT;

echo "count : $count";
if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Test"
fi
```

I'm getting following error :

```
count : 2
: integer expression expected30: [: 2
```

Comment: Not clear what you mean by string and integer. Can you add some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're *all* strings in `bash`, notwithstanding your ability to do `typeset`-type things to flag them differently.

If you want to do numeric comparisons, just use `-eq` (or its brethren like `-gt`, `-le`) rather than `==`, `!=` and so on:

```
if [[ $num -eq 42 ]] ; then
    echo Found the answer
fi
```

The full range of comparison operators can be found in the `bash` manpage, under `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS`.

If you have something that you *think* should be a number and it's not working, I'll warrant it's *not* a number. Do something like:

```
echo "[$count]"
```

to make sure it doesn't have a newline at the end or, better yet, get a hex dump of it in case it holds strange characters, like Windows line endings:

```
echo -n $count | od -xcb
```

The fact that you're seeing:

```
: integer expression expected30: [: 2
```

with the `:` back at the *start* of the line, rather than the more usual:

```
-bash: [: XX: integer expression expected
```

tends to indicate the presence of a carriage return in there, which might be from `deployment.conf` having those Windows line endings (`\r\n` rather than the UNIXy `\n`).

The hex dump should make that obvious, at which point you need to go and clean up your configuration file.

Comment: '-gt' is also numeric comparison operator.

Comment: @ManikandarajS: hence the phrase `or its brethren`.

Comment: ashokhein himself have used numeric comparison operator '-gt' -  "if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then"

Comment: @paxdiablo I'm getting following error ... count : 2 : integer expression expected30: [: 2 –

Comment: @ashokhein, then it's _not_ a number. I've added some suggestions on how to check this.

Answer (score 1):

Ref : http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash

> -eq, -ne, -lt, -le, -gt, or -ge

- These are arithmetic binary operators in bash scripting.

I have checked your code,

**deployment.conf**

```
# CONF FILE 
EAR_COUNT=5
```

**testArithmetic.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
. ./deployment.conf

count=$EAR_COUNT;

echo "count : $count";
if [ $count -gt 0 ]; then
    echo "Test"
fi
```

running the above script evaluates to numeric comparison for fine. Share us your conf file contents, if you are facing any issues. If you are including the conf file in your script file, note the conf file must have valid ***BASH assignments***, which means, there should be no space before and after '=' sign.

Also, you have mentioned WAR_COUNT=3 in conf part and used 'count=$EAR_COUNT;' in script part. Please check this too.

Comment: Updated in question.I'm getting following error ... count : 2
: integer expression expected30: [: 2

Comment: @ashokhein I have tried the code you have posted, it works fine.
Try downloading from here,
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4600b360s9hb3dj/AADwY_dHsgR7LP0773ZVd1Cca?dl=0

Comment: You must be having some \r or \n characters appended in EAR_COUNT variable,  http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/146992-how-see-hidden-characters.html

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have some non-integer character like `\r` in your `EAR_COUNT` variable. **Strip all non-digits** while assigning to `count` like this:

```
count=${EAR_COUNT//[^[:digit:]]/}

echo "count : $count";
if [[ $count -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "Test"
fi
```